# how to limit tinymce filesize upload?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

Does anyone know how to limit filesize upload in tinymce ?

I'm using netadvimage plugin (http://aspnetadvimage.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)
with asp.net MVC.

Nam Vo

Comment: i figured out how to do it, it's right in the plugin js file.

Comment: you should post this as an answer and accept it